# Parent Reload on Navigate Page Flutter

Tags: flutter

How is that possible when I open the other pages.
The parent page always reloads including StreamBuilder or FutureBuilder on Widget build

Ex:
Dashboard Page
 pushNamed -> Category Page

loading category page
I also reload the dashboard build

Confused!
Should only child widgets update?

THX!!!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? But yes on returning to the parent page you might want to do that. Simply use .then on Navigator so when the user pops from category page, content inside .then will fire in the dashboard page

Comment: i am using StreamBuilder in dashboard page
when browsing it reloads each time in Category page or other pages

Comment: I found the problem, MediaQuery.of (context) .size.width
rewrites all widgets

Comment: As far as I know, mediaquery only rebuilds the build method. You can achieve it by setstate also

Comment: I was wrong, all widgets continue to reload

Comment: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6   ????

Comment: Theme.of (context) apparently reconstructed the various widgets
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53967863/1928341